# How long does the stuff I get with [gear] last in The Sprawl?

Tags: the-sprawl

Pretty simple example, really:

I'm playing *The Sprawl*. Earlier during the session, I **hit the street** to buy a high-powered sniper rifle, and I rolled 10+ so I scored 1 [gear] as a bonus.

Now I spot a nasty killbot, and I narrate how that my [gear] is some AP ammo my black-market arms-dealer threw in when I bought my sweet new gun (this is a very straightforward application of "**produce equipment**").

I use the AP ammo to punch a nasty hole in the robot and the team moves on to seize our objective.

So far, this is all a very straightforward application of the rules (combined with some cool narration that I'm glossing over here). What happens to my AP ammo afterward, though?

- Is it gone after I narrate blasting the killbot?
- Do I have it for the rest of the mission?
- Do I have a inexhaustible-unless-the-fiction-calls-for-it supply that I can use in the next session as well?

In other words, is the equipment I just got through [gear] any different mechanically than the what I would get if I went out and purposefully bought it using my actual cred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have played several games based on Apocalypse World, albeit *The Sprawl* is not one of them. I will however assume that you have already looked for specific rules on how this specific game treats ammunitions and you found none.

Usually, the philosophy behind those games assumes that once you buy a resource, you have enough of it to last until the narrative mandates that the lack of it might be a problem.

If you get a bow in Dungeon World, it comes with two or three (I can't remember the exact number) ammo checkboxes. One of the options when you roll a 9- on a ranged attack is that you consume ammo, and you uncheck one of the boxes. You then need to replenish your ammo again.

If this is not your usual standard ammunition but something stronger that grants you the capability to do something different narratively (in DW, you get a magical arrow that can pierce the scales of a dragon, other less magical attacks including regular ammo being ineffective), well, that could be a bad thing that happens on a 6-: you lose some resources.

In *The Sprawl*, this falls under the "use up their resources" MC move:

> Use up their resources
>
> Tech can malfunction, tires go flat, drones crash, substandard cyberware is... well... substandard, guns run out of ammo, cyberzombies break things. Inflicting harm is all well and good, but often its more interesting to take away something else and see what they can come up with to get out of the new situation.

Comment: Thanks! I found a relevant MC move in the book that matches the "lose some resources on a 6-" situation you described and added it to your answer. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what the Missions chapter has to say about [gear]:

> This is particularly relevant for [gear]: you can only produce equipment that you could reasonably have in your possession or could have obtained relatively easily.
>
> [...]
>
> As a rule, anything that cost 1 or 2 Cred, or which might have been easily picked up at or stolen from a location the character visited previously in the story would count. Remember that the player has to narrate how they got the gear. That might include buying it, in which case they should pay for it in Cred or favours as appropriate. It might also include stealing it, which might result in enemies. Gear obtained with **produce equipment** is as permanent as any other gear the characters buy.

Based on your narration, it sounds like this is something your usual supplier tossed in for free, not something you bought. So, having it just be enough to drop one killbot makes sense? Maybe you can add the +AP tag to one extra engagement since sniper rifles tend to be more frugal with their ammo?

Of course, if you wanted to say you paid for it, well, you get what you pay for, and from an ammo perspective it's probably best to think about it as "enough to do the mission, or until the GM says you're out".